# validates_uniqueness_of triggers wrong thing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a shoulda test:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of :link }
```

And it gives an error

```
undefined method `truncate' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/crowdfunding.rb:100:in `truncate_overview'
```

Which means it triggers before_save callback called `truncate_overview`.

So I assume the way it checks uniqueness is it saves record once, and then tries second time.

Is there a way to make it NOT trigger that before_save callback?

Comment: Can you show more of your test code? Testing uniqueness with shoulda can be tricky.

Comment: What exactly do you wanna see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't.  `shoulda`'s validators work by setting various values and calling `valid?` to see if it behaves as expected.